# Graph algorithm selection

Tags: algorithm, neo4j, cypher, graph-theory, detection

I have a graph with three types of nodes (supplier ,contract ,buyer)with the following relations

HasSupplier ( between contract and supplier)
HasBuyer(between contract and buyer)

In the context of a fraud detection  ,I want to detect anomalies in my graph (for exemple buyers always associated with the same suppliers).
Which graph algorithm should I use ,
PS I m working with neo4j

Comment: It depends on what anomalies you want to look for.  In your example, you do not need a graph algorithm at all.  A database query will give you the fraction of times a buyer is associated with their most frequent buyer.  Then you compare that fraction with some trigger level, above which you become suspicious.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "for exemple buyers always associated with the same suppliers", is there a particular number of associations that are considered fraud? 
I think the problem is missing the constraints.

Answer (score 0):

For your example a graph algorithm is not needed.

Read your data into a database and use a couple of queries, like this:

Assume that a contract may have only one buyer and one supplier.

Your database needs 3 tables

```
**Buyer tabl**e
buyer_index
...

**Supplier table**
supplier_index
...

**Contract table**
Buyer_index
Supplier_index
...
```

To check for suspicious buyer always using same supplier

```
LOOP over buyers
  count_buyer_contracts = SELECT count FROM contract WHERE buyer_index = buyer
  most_freq_supplier_count = 0
  LOOP over suppliers
     supplier_count = SELECT count FROM contract 
                   WHERE buyer_index = buyer
                   AND supplier_index = supplier
     IF supplier_count > most_freq_supplier_count
         most_freq_supplier_count = supplier_count
  IF most_freq_supplier_count / count_buyer_contracts > suspicion_level
      PRINT buyer is suspicious
```

Comment: thank you that is exactly what i want but I dont have a threshold so i can compare that's why i wanted to use a graph algorithm to detect anomalies (suspicious relationships)

Comment: No algorithm, graph or otherwise, can let you avoid the necessity to specify a threshold.